# javascript/jQuery grouping elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, grouping

Given a list of dynamically generated checkboxes and labels (not html labels, just text), what is the best way to group this information into a more manageable (and more easily displayable), list of information. For example, here is part of a list I am working with:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="Alabama"/> Alabama <br> 
 <input type="checkbox" value="Alaska"/> Alaska <br> 
 <input type="checkbox" value="Arizona"/> Arizona<br> 
 <input type="checkbox" value="Arksansas"/> Arksansas<br>
```

...rest of the states.

Idealy, I'd like to get them to the point where they are in 4 or 5 equal width columns so they don't take up then entire length of the screen, as one long list. I could probably hack around and get something that works, but I am more interested in finding an appropriate solution to this issue. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: classes on the `<inputs> and using `<div>`s and `<span>`s then setting `css`

Comment: If you want columns you're probably going to need to divide your output accordingly - you won't be able to just use checkbox, text, <br>.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Often sites use a letter-index (A, B, C etc.) that is clickable that hide/shows different DIVs, each holding a list of states by letter. This is s simple tab-pattern.

You can use one of the many tab JS libraries to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is very rough and off the top of my head, but something like this should split any number of elements into arbitrary groupings:

```
var objects = $("input[type=checkbox]");
var groupings = 3; // think columns
var factor = objects.length / columns;
var groups = []

for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    groups[Math.round(i / factor)] = objects[i];
}
```

So now you have all of your checkbox items split into three groupings accessible via the `groups` array. You could them wrap them in divs and create columns, or some similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTML like:

```
<label><input name="state" type="checkbox" value="Alabama"/> Alabama</label>
<label><input name="state" type="checkbox" value="Alaska"/> Alaska</label>
<label><input name="state" type="checkbox" value="Arizona"/> Arizona</label> 
<label><input name="state" type="checkbox" value="Arksansas"/> Arksansas</label>
```

And then group them using jQuery

```
$('input[name="state"]').each(function(index, element) {
    if ((index % 4) == 3) {
      $(element).closest('label').after($('<br/>'));
    }
});​
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5f86w/